# How to refactor ternary into Enum Map with properties?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code to style a button based off of a select box:

```
const buttonStyles = {
    backgroundColor: buttonStyle === 'Black' ? colors.interactiveForegroundSecondary : buttonStyle === 'Green' ? colors.backgroundInverseSecondary : buttonStyle === 'White' ? colors.backgroundPrimary : buttonStyle === 'Lime Green' ? colors.graphTertiary : '',
    color: buttonStyle === 'Black' ? colors.textInversePrimary : buttonStyle === 'Green' ? colors.textInversePrimary : buttonStyle === 'White' ? colors.interactiveForegroundSecondary : buttonStyle === 'Lime Green' ? colors.backgroundInverseSecondary : '',
    "&:hover": {
      background: buttonStyle === 'Black' ? colors.backgroundInversePrimary : buttonStyle === 'Green' ? colors.accentPrimary : buttonStyle === 'White' ? colors.errorBackground : buttonStyle === 'Lime Green' ? colors.backgroundInverseSecondary : '',
      color: buttonStyle === 'Lime Green' ? colors.graphTertiary : ''
    },
  } as CrateStyleObject
```

And I am trying to refactor this into an Enum map in typescript like so:

```
enum ButtonBackground {
  Black = colors.interactiveForegroundSecondary,
  Green = colors.backgroundInverseSecondary,
  White = colors.backgroundPrimary,
  Lime Green = colors.graphTertiary ,
}
const submitBackground = (Object.keys(ButtonBackground) as (keyof typeof ButtonBackground)[]).map(
  (key, index) => {
    console.log(key);
    return ButtonBackground[key] + index;
  },
);

then setting it here on the component: 

<Button
  style={
    buttonStyles
  }
  type="submit">
{text}
</Button/>
```

But I am having trouble assigning `colors.interactiveForegroundSecondary` to one of the keys since it is not a string.

Also the background color and color of the button needs to change based off of the selected value – would I have to create a separate Enum for each of the Background Color/Text Color as well as the Hover Background Color / Text Color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be convenient to create a separate enum for `ButtonBackgroundColor`, `ButtonColor`, `ButtonBackgroundColorOnHover` and `ButtonColorOnHover`.

I'm not sure though why are you trying to iterate over the enum when you actually want to set the `buttonStyles` according only to the value of the `buttonStyle` variable. I would go about it like this:

```
const buttonStyle = 'Lime Green' // For example

// You'll need to remove whitespace because enums cannot have two words
const buttonStyleWithNoWhitespace = buttonStyle.replace(/\s/g, '')

enum ButtonBackground {
  Black = colors.interactiveForegroundSecondary,
  Green = colors.backgroundInverseSecondary,
  White = colors.backgroundPrimary,
  LimeGreen = colors.graphTertiary,
}

enum ButtonColor {
  Black = colors.backgroundInversePrimary,
  Green = colors.accentPrimary,
  White = colors.errorBackground,
  LimeGreen = colors.backgroundInverseSecondary,
}

enum ButtonBackgroundOnHover {
  Black = colors.backgroundInversePrimary,
  Green = colors.accentPrimary,
  White = colors.errorBackground,
  LimeGreen = colors.backgroundInverseSecondary,
}

enum ButtonColorOnHover {
  Black = '',
  Green = '',
  White = '',
  LimeGreen = colors.graphTertiary,
}

const buttonStyles = {
    backgroundColor: ButtonBackground[buttonStyle as keyof typeof ButtonBackground],
    color: ButtonColor[buttonStyle as keyof typeof ButtonColor],
    "&:hover": {
        background: ButtonBackgroundOnHover[buttonStyle as keyof typeof ButtonBackgroundOnHover],
        color: ButtonColorOnHover[buttonStyle as keyof typeof ButtonColorOnHover]
    }
} as CreateStyleObject

<Button 
    style={buttonStyles} 
    type="submit">
    {text}
</Button/>
```

The `as keyof typeof Enum` makes the usage of enums a bit too much when you can use a simple object for each of them, but perhaps there are other specific reasons that makes using enums necessary.